# Hiding Empty Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on a code that hides empty cells ,but the problem is i want it to start hiding at a certain range ("A9:A12") not at the beginning of the sheet.
here is my program :

```
Sub EmptyRow()
'Dim s As String
po = Range("A9:A12").Count
Range("A8").Activate

For i = 1 To po
 s = i & ":" & i
 If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
     Rows(s).Select
     Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next

End Sub
```

The program keeps on hiding cells from the beginning, how do I set it up so it deletes from the range i want it to. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can even make your code shorter like this:

```
For i = 9 To 12
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value)
Next i
```

Thus, the result of the `Hidden` property would be dependent on whether the `Cells(i,1)` is empty. It is easier to understand and to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Check the solution below. In case you need to change your affected area, just change the value of `targetRange`.

```
Sub EmptyRow()
Dim targetRange as Range, po as Long, i as Long
Set targetRange = Range("A9:A12")
po = targetRange.Count

With targetRange
    For i = 1 To po
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9:A12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

---

`SpecialCells` results in run-time error if no cells are found, but that can be checked:

```
If [CountBlank(Sheet1!A9:A12)] Then _
    [Sheet1!A9:A12].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

or ignored:

```
On Error Resume Next
[Sheet1!A9:A12].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of bits like `select`

```
Sub EmptyRow()
    For i = 9 To 12
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```